# Is something wrong with wrapper classes for C string functions?

Tags: c++

I have some C++ code written in C-style.
For some reasons I can't use C++ string and IO libraries, so for strings handling I should use only functions like `sprintf`, `itoa`, etc.

I want to replace C-style which requires temporary buffers
    char buf[12];
    itoa(x, buf, 16);
    set_some_text(buf);

by the following code

```
class i2a
{
public:
    explicit i2a(int value) { ::sprintf(buf, "%d", value); }
    operator const char* () const { return buf; }
private:
    char buf[12];
};

// usage:
set_some_text(i2a(x));
```

(Such classes can be written for `char<->wchar_t` convertions, etc.)

I see some cases when such classes will be dangerous: 
For example, one can write

```
const char* someMeaningfulName = i2a(x);
// the right code should be i2a someMeaningfulName(x); or i2a someMeaningfulName = i2a(x);
set_some_text(someMeaningfulName);
```

In more complex case, a function which accepts text will not copy it, but will save pointer to it somewhere. For example it may be

```
class Foo { .... const char* p; };
Foo f(const char* text) { ... foo.p = text; return foo; }
```

it can be really unobvious, unlike `const char*` variable.

Is there a way to make such classes more secure?

---

**Upd**: why not std::string, boost::lexical_cast, boost::format, etc :
The code should work when compiled with -fno-except (C++ exceptions disabled - no `throw`, no stack unwinding). Also it should keep working on low memory conditions.
`std::string`, streams uses heap-allocated memory and at least throws `bad_alloc`.
When we have no free heap memory, usually we still have some kilobytes of stack (for example to write to user that we are out of memory and then make proper cleanup).

Comment: If you've got a very weird system such that you can't use even the most basic C++ classes, please be more specific. Most of the obvious solutions will break on not-really-C++ systems.

Comment: "i2a someMeaningfulName(x);" what's *i2a* here? another class?

Comment: @rageshctech oh, thanks, it the same class. (fixed it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros are also written in this way. Calling the constructor directly like `i2a(x)` will create a temporary object that will live until the function to which it is passed is complete. So here: `do_some(i2a(x))`, the temporary object will be there until `do_some()` is complete.

Refer the **Example** section (*example 2*) of this [msdn document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Here,

```
const char* someMeaningfulName = i2a(x);
set_some_text(someMeaningfulName);
```

This will not work as, the temporary object will be freed on the first statement itself. `someMeaningfulName` will be garbage. If you feel that as lack of security, all I can say is:

> **That's how Microsoft does it!**

Comment: It will be nice if there is a better/more secure way, I agree!

Answer (score 0):

You will always get somewhere into troubles if you use const char* for your local variables.
You will have the same with const char* someMeaningfulName = std::string("foo").c_str();

If you can you should declare your local variable like this :

```
i2a someMeaningfulName(x);
set_some_text(someMeaningfulName);
```

You can also consider adding a copy constructor to i2a to avoid sharing the buffer between two instances.